# How to increase the time for which the Microsoft Speech Service SDK listens in a single go?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-speech, microsoft-speech-api

I am using MS speech service sdk for speech to text conversion. When I speak, my speech  is converted to text after 60 seconds even if I haven't stopped speaking. It basically considers it one chunk and starts processing it. What can I do to increase this timeout?

I want the service to keep listening even if I speak for 80 seconds and convert the speech to text only after I have finished speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us and posting this query.

Could you please use the `SegmentationSilenceTimeoutMs` property and check if that helps ?

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/propertyid?view=azure-node-latest) which talks about this setting in detail:

[image]

The default behaviors for non-speech silence in input audio may not produce the expected results if the user is speaking faster or slower than usual. Please refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp#change-how-silence-is-handled), which explains how to handle this timeout.

Also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409606/how-to-change-the-default-timeout-of-azure-speech-which-of-15-seconds-to-somethi) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.endsilencetimeout?view=netframework-4.8) has some suggestions on the timeout settings like InitialSilenceTimeout and EndSilenceTimeout available within the speech sdk. Hope this helps.

Comment: `SegmentationSilenceTimeoutMs` is different. It detects that many milliseconds of silence in your speech and considers the part before the silence as one chunk and processes it. What I want is for speech recognizer to keep listening for at least 80 seconds if I keep speaking and only after I stop, convert that speech to text. Right now, it only listens for 60 seconds at most.

Comment: Thanks for getting back and clarifying your ask. AFAIK, Microsoft Speech Service SDK has a maximum duration limit for a single utterance, which is 60 seconds. This limit is set by service and can't be changed.  As a workaround, you can use continuous recognition for longer samples. In continuous recognition, SDK keeps listening and providing results as long as you don’t stop it. Refer this [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-continuous-recognition) which you can refer. Hope this helps

Comment: I am using continuous recognition. It has this behavior as well.